# i want to make i as textbox and take data to fill tabel lab.work vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button19_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button19.Click
    load_analyzes_details_cbc()


    Dim salesId, analyzess_id As Integer
    Dim rresult As Integer




    Dim cmdInsert As New SqlCommand()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select *from analyzes_details where analyzess_id='1'", connSQLServer)

    connSQLServer.Open()

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt_analyzes_details_cbc)
    For Each row In dt_analyzes_details_cbc.Rows


        salesId = Convert.ToInt32(row("details_id").ToString())
        analyzess_id = Convert.ToInt32(row("analyzess_id").ToString())
        For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox - 1
            rresult = Convert.ToInt32(Val(i).ToString())

            cmdInsert.CommandText = "Insert into lab_work(sales_id,sub_id,analyzesss_id,result) values(" & Label1.Text & "," & salesId & "," & analyzess_id & "," & rresult & ")"

            cmdInsert.Connection = connSQLServer

            cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    Next
    'Next
    cmd.Dispose()

    connSQLServer.Close()

    load_lab_work()
End Sub
```

Comment: rresult = Convert.ToInt32(Val(i).ToString())

Comment: Still error    For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox - 1
            rresult = Convert.ToInt32(Val(i).ToString())

Comment: All code is correct BUT  when you add the code     For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox - 1
            rresult = Convert.ToInt32(Val(i).ToString())  An error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code..

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = "Insert into lab_work(sales_id,sub_id,analyzesss_id,result) values(" & Label1.Text & "," & salesId & "," & analyzess_id & "," & rresult & ")"
```

`".text"` Missing in textbox id

Your code will be

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = "Insert into lab_work(sales_id,sub_id,analyzesss_id,result) values(" & Label1.Text & "," & salesId.Text & "," & analyzess_id.Text & "," & rresult.Text & ")"
```

Comment: NOT WORKING MY ERROR IN 'For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox - 1
            rresult = Convert.ToInt32(Val(i).ToString())'

Comment: All code is correct BUT  when you add the code     For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox - 1
            rresult = Convert.ToInt32(Val(i).ToString())  An error occurs

Comment: Which textbox value are getting in for loop? (TextBox - 1)

Comment: MY TEXTBOX 1 TO 18 TO FILL COLUMN RESULT

Comment: sales_details_id sales_id sub_id analyzesss_id result
3800 6 2 1 0
3801 6 3 1 0
3802 6 4 1 0
3803 6 5 1 0
3804 6 6 1 0
3805 6 7 1 0
3806 6 8 1 0
3807 6 9 1 0
3808 6 10 1 0
3809 6 11 1 0
3810 6 12 1 0
3811 6 13 1 0
3812 6 14 1 0
3813 6 15 1 0
3814 6 16 1 0
3815 6 17 1 0
3816 6 18 1 0
3817 6 19 1 0

Comment: this is my table

Comment: I want 18 textbox ids?

Comment: TextBox1.Text
        TextBox2.Text
        TextBox3.Text
        TextBox4.Text
        TextBox5.Text
        TextBox6.Text
        TextBox7.Text
        TextBox8.Text
        TextBox9.Text
        TextBox10.Text
        TextBox11.Text
        TextBox12.Text
        TextBox13.Text
        TextBox14.Text
                                                                                                                                 .TextBox15.Text
        TextBox16.Text

        TextBox17.Text
        TextBox18.Text

Comment: Please try the for loop...  For i As Integer = 0 To intNoTextBoxes
CreateString += TextBox(i).Text
Next

Comment: refer the below link.. https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/393674/easier-way-to-read-from-multiple-textboxes

Comment: is code is work but i have Duplication...........................................................

Comment: What duplications?